# Smart way to turn wifi on/off with netplan if ethernet is available or not?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, netplan

I have ubuntu 18.04 and as far as I understood, it uses "netplan".
I find out on the web a few ideas to switch wifi on/off when cable is off/on, but most of them uses older fashion.

I liked this idea I found (using /etc/network/interfaces), very simple and clear in my opinion (rather than putting a script somewhere you may forgot later).

```
 iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.1.7
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 192.168.1.1
         post-up ifconfig wlan0 down
         post-down ifconfig wlan0 up
```

But /etc/network/interfaces seems not used anymore by netplan.

Is there something similar that could be configured in netplan ?

here are more informations:

```
roger@mini:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
roger@mini:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
roger@mini:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Mot de passe de roger : 
  *-network                 
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       numéro de série: 9c:b6:d0:8b:33:c5
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-51-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources: irq:171 mémoire:dc000000-dc1fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 2
       nom logique: enx106530a39639
       numéro de série: 10:65:30:a3:96:39
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.11 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.15 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
roger@mini:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
roger@mini:~$
```

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: Hi! added in the question!  (wifi in intergrated, but ethernet is from a thunderbolt dock).

Comment: You may not have netplan installed. Check with `dpkg -l *netplan* | grep ii`. Also, your interfaces are enx106530a39639 and wlp2s0 (not eth0 and wlan0). Your script is a NetworkManager script. For networkd-dispatcher, and NetworkManaager dispatcher, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/networkd-dispatcher.8.html and https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/NetworkManager.8.html and https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html

Answer (score 0):

The tool for triggering additional actions on a network change if using networkd is `networkd-dispatcher`.